# Physics simulation, adjusting pixels to meters?

Tags: java, swing, simulation

So I have been trying to code a physics simulation. I'm starting small by simulating a free fall. I'm using Java Jframe and some methods from awt library in java. The problem that I have been facing, though, is with adjusting the parameters to make my simulation more life like. My game while loop runs at a constant 60 FPS, which means each loop is taking 16 ms. Each time I update, I perform those laws:

```
this.velX = this.velX +  (accX)*delta;
this.velY = this.velY +  (accY) * delta ;

this.velY = this.velY * 0.9;


this.x = this.x + (int) ((this.velX) * delta); 
this.y = this.y + (int) ((this.velY)* delta);
```

However, since I'm converting to int, the values are always getting back to 0 since they are so small. And the draw methods for the shapes only accept int (which I think is understandable, right? ) I was wondering if there would be a solution for that? The ball would be stuck and its movement would not be noticeable (if it's moving at all).

I tried passing delta as 1, and it worked nicely, but it's too fast though and I don't think it's realistic. Therefore, it would be super helpful if someone can give me general ideas about such a problem.

Comment: "16 ml seconds" - 16 milliliter seconds?? I guess that's supposed to be "ms" = milliseconds?

Comment: It sounds like you are reading your coordinates from the same place that renders them - this is exactly the cause of your problem in my eyes. Try storing coordinates in some dedicated object that can accept them in whatever form you actually need them (i.e. in `double` or whatever) and then only convert to `int` as you are rendering them.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I edited it.

Comment: Having dedicated object will also allow your physics computation to not depend on application frame ticker, which is a good thing, I think.

Comment: Thank you @M.Prokhorov!! I did what you suggested. The ball is now moving with delta 0.016 s but it's so slow though!! My window is 1000 pixels in height. Do you think I should make some conversion here?

Comment: Increase your values for acceleration. Why do you multiply the y velocity with 0.9?

Comment: My acc is 9.8 (trying to simulate gravity) and even without multiplying by 0.9, it still moves slowly!

Comment: I guess you need some scaling between meters and pixels. You would want to make calculations based on meters etc. only your display should make a "conversion" from meters to pixels. That way you can even implement "zooming" without the need to recalculate your data.

Comment: Thank you so much all! Problem resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in these lines

```
this.x = this.x + (int) ((this.velX) * delta); 
this.y = this.y + (int) ((this.velY)* delta);
```

lets term the later part of the equations `((this.velX) * delta) and ((this.velY) * delta)` as `deltaX and deltaY`

So the equations should become

```
this.x = this.x + (int) deltaX; 
this.y = this.y + (int) deltaY;
```

Now, issue here is that you're converting the `deltaX and deltaY` to integer and thus reducing their contribution to the `x and y` positions to zero.

Even if the changes are small over a long time (over a number of frames) the contribution will become significant.

Suppose the change `deltaX` is `.1` it should be able to add `1` pixel shift in `10` frames.

If your `draw` function takes integers only then you should be converting the position values at that line not before that, they should be `float or double` for all other purposes.

So equations should be

```
this.x = this.x + this.velX * delta; //this.x is float
this.y = this.y + this.velY* delta;  //this.x is float

draw( (int)x, (int)y )
```

It should work now.

**Note:** Also I don't know how you're maintaining constant frame rate, as Java can't do that. You will have to take variable frame rate into account. That you've already done by using `delta`. Delta value should not be constant and should be calculated at the end of every frame.

Comment: Thank you so much!! this actually works!! I'm using the typical thread.sleep to sleep for what have been left from the 16 ms after processing input. is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, `Thread.sleep()` doesn't guarantee that Thread will wake up at the exact time specified. So you can calculate the actual `delta` value at the of sleep using `System.currentTimeMillis()`. That should work perfectly.

Comment: @user70319, Better yet, try using a `java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService`, it has this handy method `scheduleAtFixedRate` which will allow you to run some code every x time units. Do watch out if your scheduled code is too slow to complete execution in time, you should catch those instances and handle them.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov ScheduledExecutorService uses `System.nanoTime()`, which also doesn't guarantee the accuracy of fixed rate. It can not  be done as there are other tasks running on the CPU and OS decides when to schedule tasks.

Comment: @11thdimension, yes, CPU times are strange like that. But at least using `ExecutorService` his code will not depend on homegrown scheduling solutions (and he will be able to change solution as required). If JDK one will not suffice, he will be able to search for a library that does better.